# Running JPanels in their own threads.

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jpanel, jcomponent

I'm having a bit of trouble with Swing components.

In one `JFrame`, I have a `GLCanvas` and a `JEditorPane` separated by a `JSplitPane`. This configuration makes display response choppy in both panels.

However, when I place the `GLCanvas` and `JEditorPane` each in their own `JFrame`, display response is great.

I would assume this is because, in the second case, all operations on these components are performed in separate threads. If so, my questions are as follows:

Is it possible to run components in their own threads? Or is there a better way I should be doing this?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: No, they are rendered in the same thread.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that the poor performance in the first case has more to do with [*Mixing heavy and light components*](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/mixing/). Like most graphics APIs, Swing uses a [single, event dispatch thread](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html) to update the screen; I'm guessing that JOGL must adhere to the same restriction. At the same time, there are [many ways](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/threadwatch) to perform work in another thread and communicate with the graphics environment.

Comment: Thanks, This makes sense. I'll investigate this further. Matthew's website seems to be a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

I think your assumption is incorrect.  All Swing draw operations occur on the same thread.

Perhaps you could expand on your description of 'choppy' ?   Maybe this is double buffering vs non-double buffering issue?

Comment: By choppy, I mean there is a lag between a keypress and the text in the editor pane being updated. As well, moving the split pane is laggy. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like @trashgod is right. `GLCanvas` is a "heavyweight" component descendent from awt `Canvas`. To see if it is really a case **I suggest replacing `GLCanvas` with `GLJPanel`**, which is a Swing component descendant from `JPanel`.

Comment: I've actually tried this, and while it solves the problem with the lag in EditorPane, it has a much slower refresh rate compared to GLCanvas. I really need to maintain a good frame rate in the rendering view.

Comment: I does have slower refresh rate, because of addition overhead of Swing pipeline. As I see it now you really have only one choice - to separate your elements if you want to get rid of the "choppinnes"